# Facing a crash while adding object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I am getting this crash message while adding object to NSMutableArray :

> -[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000238d80

Fetching the array type , the result shows SwiftDeferredNSArray.
Is there a way to convert the array or is there something which I am doing wrong?

The code :

```
var List = NSMutableArray()
```

Adding the object:

```
List.add(obj)
```

Comment: are you sure the array is mutable?

Comment: Yes I am declaring it as an NSMutableArray

Comment: can you post some code here?

Comment: show your  tried code

Comment: Added code above

Comment: It's a swift, don't use NSMutableArray

Comment: In Swift 3+ prefers Swift equivalent, avoid NSStuffs. Avoid naming your var starting with an uppercase. Also, I tend to think that at some point in your code you do `List = something` and since that `something` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray` it may crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSMutableArray` this way in Swift

```
var data : [Any] = []
```

where `Any` is the Object type.

then you can append child using this,

```
for i in 1...15 {
    data.append("New Object \(i)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro its simple please use this

```
var List:NSMutableArray = []
 List.add()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Like this in Swift for declare

> ```
> var arrDrop :NSMutableArray = []
>   arrDrop.add(valueData)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSMutableArray this way in Swift

var List : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

List.add(obj)